# make my javascript function requirejs/amd friendly?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I have created a javascript library which adds only one global object to the global space.

The global object happens to be a function and the name of the function matches the name of the file.

This is how it looks:

**filename:** myfunction.js

**code:**

```
myfunction = function() {
   ...
};
```

How do I make my library compliant with amd and require.js ?

Comment: check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953589/what-is-typeof-define-function-defineamd-used-for)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The Requirejs Docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#deffunc) tell you all about how to make an AMD compliant module. However, information on how to keep a module working when used without AMD (`<script>` tag) is hard to find there. Anyway, when in a Requrirejs context, the "define" method is defined. Otherwise, the example below just uses window.x (not the most elegant solution) to expose the function to the global space from within a closure.

```
(function (module) {
    if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define(function () { return module; });
    } else {
        window.myfunction = module.myfunction;
    }
}({
    myfunction: function () {
        /* ... */
    }
}));
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14033636

Answer (score 1):

I have found a great post that explains the whole process.

http://ifandelse.com/its-not-hard-making-your-library-support-amd-and-commonjs/

In a nutshell, the author suggested the following pattern :

** Here, postal.js is a AMD/Commonjs compliant module.

```
(function (root, factory) {

if(typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
// Now we're wrapping the factory and assigning the return
// value to the root (window) and returning it as well to
// the AMD loader.
define(["postal"], function(postal){
  return (root.myModule = factory(postal));
});
} else if(typeof module === "object" && module.exports) { 
// I've not encountered a need for this yet, since I haven't
// run into a scenario where plain modules depend on CommonJS
// *and* I happen to be loading in a CJS browser environment
// but I'm including it for the sake of being thorough
module.exports = (root.myModule = factory(require("postal")));
} 
else {   //node.js diverges from the CommonJS spec a bit by using module.  So, to use it in other common js environments
root.myModule = factory(root.postal);}}(this, function(postal) {//passing this as the root argument, and our module method from earlier as the factory argument. If we run this in the browser, this, will be the window.

 var sub;
   var ch = postal.channel("myModule");
   var myModule = {
     sayHi:function() {
            ch.publish("hey.yall", { msg: "myModule sez hai" });
     },
     dispose: function() {
            sub.unsubscribe();
     }};return myModule;}));
```

Comment: really great tutorial thanks for posting

Comment: @BasheerAL-MOMANI I am glad it helped you. May be a upvote!!! lol.