# How does the Levenshtein module interact with NodeJS module system?

Tags: node.js, levenshtein-distance

I am looking here:

https://github.com/gf3/Levenshtein/blob/master/lib/levenshtein.js

I see that the code begins like this:

```
(function(root, factory){
  if (typeof define == 'function' && typeof define.amd == 'object' && define.amd) {
    define(function(){
      return factory(root);
    });
  } else if (typeof module == 'object' && module && module.exports) {
    module.exports = factory(root);
  } else {
    root.Levenshtein = factory(root);
  }
}(this, function(root){
```

I've never seen this before. What does it mean? What does "root" mean?

If I add this to the package.json file of my NodeJS app, then how do I use this inner function:

```
 // Levenshtein distance
 function Levenshtein( str_m, str_n )
```

All the examples use this inner function, but I don't know how to reach it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is 'typeof define === 'function' && define\['amd'\]' used for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953589/what-is-typeof-define-function-defineamd-used-for)

Comment: Just use it like normal. You may notice that it does `module.exports` as usual if it detects that it's running in node.js (module object exist)

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

> What does "root" mean?

`root` is the first argument passed to this [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript), which (as you see on line 11) is `this`. At the "top level" of a JavaScript file in Node.js, `this` points to [the `global` namespace object](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global). In the browser it points to `window`.

> All the examples use this inner function, but I don't know how to reach it.

That's not a question, but this is how you use it in Node.js:

```
const Levenshtein = require('levenshtein');

const lev = new Levenshtein('bar', 'baz');
console.log(lev.distance); // => 1
```

> What does it mean?

The purpose of all of this is to make this code work whether you use `require` in Node.js, an AMD module loader, or a `<script>` tag in the browser.

If you break it down, the code isn't too hard to understand. Let's start with the anonymous `function` on line 11, which is a "factory" function that just returns the `Levenshtein` constructor, like so:

```
function factory(root) {
  // ...
  function Levenshtein( str_m, str_n ) {
    // ...
  }
  // ...
  return Levenshtein
}
```

(In the case of the Levenshtein module, the `root` argument is never actually used in the "factory" function. Go figure.)

Now let's back up to the first line. Here an anonymous `function` is declared, which basically works like this:

```
function iife(root, factory) {
  const Levenshtein = factory(root);

  if (anAMDLoaderIsLoadingMe()) {
    // AMD loaders supply a `define` function
    define(function() { return Levenshtein; });
  } else if (nodeJsIsLoadingMe()) {
    // Node.js supplies the `module.exports` object
    module.exports = Levenshtein;
  } else {
    // In a browser, so `root` is `window`
    root.Levenshtein = Levenshtein;
  }
}
```

Finally, these two functions are used like this:

```
iife(this, factory);
```

That's it! The reason these functions are used anonymously instead of giving them sensible names like `iife` and `factory` is so that they don't clash with other functions that you might define (or that other, less well-behaved modules define). This isn't a possibility in Node.js, but it is in the browser.