# Cannot run javascript umd command line tool: [TypeError: _.any is not a function]

Tags: javascript, node.js, umd

I'm just trying out [urequire](https://github.com/anodynos/uRequire) but cant get a simple example to work. In windows on my desktop i have a "SomeFolder" folder with a single file in it called test.js. It looks like this...

```
define([], function() {
  return {the:'PersonViewModule'}
});
```

I run the following command...

```
c:\Users\blah\Desktop> urequire UMD SomeFolder/ -o build

[uRequire/process/Bundle] ERRor: Unknown error while 
loading/refreshing/processing 'test.js'.
error.nested = [TypeError: _.any is not a function]
[uRequire/urequireCMD] ERRor: uRequireCmd done() #1 with errors in 0.023secs.
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Seems like an issue with underscore or lodash but I tried a few local npm installs with and without -g flag on both of those libs with no luck.

Submitted a github issue [here](https://github.com/anodynos/uRequire/issues/70)

Comment: Hey & thanks for the report - I am sure its not your fault - its the [lodash v4 removing _.any alias in favor of _.some among others](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Changelog#notable-changes) - I will look into it... Are you on the latest version urequire@0.7.0-beta.25 ? Lets keep the issue updated on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when i install urequire with the following command it works...

```
npm install urequire@0.7.0-beta.25
```

URequire does not work (showing the errors described above) when installed like this...

```
npm install urequire
```